# How to add an event listener inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, events, listener

I want to add an event listener into my function to initiate the game aka for the computer to choose a random word from my word object with keys. I want the player to click on the word category aka the key and for the computer to choose a random word from that array.
I already have an event listener for word categories on my game board. Here's my current code without an event listener in it

```
const words = {
    arm: ['humerus', 'ulna', 'radius'],
    leg: ['femur', 'tibia', 'fibula'],
    skull: ['frontal', 'occipital', 'temporal'],

}
const wordArray = words.arm;
secretWord = wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length)];
```

Here's my cached element and my working event listener that pushes buttons:

```
const wordCategoriesButton = document.getElementById('words-container');

wordCategoriesButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const categoryValue = event.target.textContent;
    console.log('Category button clicked:', categoryValue);
})
```

I am attempting this, and it's not working:

```
const wordArray = wordCategoriesButton;
secretWord = wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length)];
console.log(secretWord)
```

Thank you for your help and advice in advance! :)

Comment: `wordCategoriesButton` is an element (`const wordCategoriesButton = document.getElementById('words-container');`), but you are attempting to treat it as an array with `const wordArray = wordCategoriesButton;
    secretWord = wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length)];`

Comment: What do you mean by "add an event listener into my function"? You haven't shown any function here (except for the one called by the event listener).

Comment: Do you want to use the button's value as the key into the `words` object?